# Make awk output variable number of columns of data

Tags: linux, unix, awk

New *awk* user here. I am a user of a simulation that outputs a single ascii file that is M rows by N columns, space delimited, with newline characters at the end of each row. The number of rows doesn't matter, but it's in the thousands. The number of columns is in the hundreds. I want to break up this large file into multiple smaller files with, say, 50 columns of data.

The following use of *awk* will reliably break the file using the whitespace as the delimiter and print the first 3 columns of data:

```
awk ‘{split($0,a)} {print a[1] “ “ a[2] " " a[3]}’ huge_file.txt > small_file.txt
```

Is there any easy way of making it print out 50 columns of data without a very long print statement? Ideally, I would like it to print out columns from X to X+49.

So far, I have had to use the split function to get *awk* to break the file in a manner I find predictable. When I try to use something similar to:

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}' huge_file.txt > small_file.txt
```

it never works right, even if I use `FS = " "`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have curly quotes in your first `awk` command. Make sure you turn off Smart Quotes when editing and pasting code.

Comment: What's a curly quote?

Comment: @tink This: `“` or this: `‘`. And it is different from this: `"` or this: `'`.

Comment: it would help if you provide a sample data set (eg, 4 lines of 10 columns, each field a few characters in length) and the expected result for splitting into, say, 3 columns of data

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I see ... `´` is called an apostrophe, though. And `“` is also just called a quotation mark, *slanted* if you want to differentiate it from `"`. The only typographical symbols I know of ever being referred to as curly are the *curly braces* `{}`.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output end explain what "it never works right" means so we can help you get the best (most robust, efficient, concise, portable, etc.) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will suit?

Make some 'test' data (220 columns X 1000 rows):

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=1000; i++) {for (j=1; j<=220; j++) {printf "%s%s", j, (j == 220 ? "\n" : " ")}}}' > test.txt

head -2 test.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220
```

Split 'test.txt' into smaller files, each containing 50 columns:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=50){for(j=i; j<=i+49; j++){printf "%s%s", $j, (j == i + 49 ? "\n" : " ") > ("small_file" i ".txt")}; close ("small_file" i ".txt")}}' test.txt

head -2 small_file*
==> small_file1.txt <==
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

==> small_file51.txt <==
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100

==> small_file101.txt <==
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150

==> small_file151.txt <==
151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200
151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200

==> small_file201.txt <==
201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220
201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220
```

With nicer formatting:

```
awk '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 50) {
        for (j = i; j <= i + 49; j++) {
            printf("%s%s", $j, (j == i + 49 ? "\n" : " ")) > ("small_file" i ".txt")
        }
        close("small_file" i ".txt")
    }
}' test.txt
```

Comment: since you're not closing files, when there are enough columns you may run out of file descriptors (eg. on my machine, gawk seems to have code to multiplex them for you (`seq 10000 | gawk --lint '{print >(""NR)}'`) but other versions just fail at around 1021)

Comment: Thanks @jhnc! I use gawk for everything and I often forget to close the files. Thanks for the correction

Comment: I think close may not be needed in this case ("in the hundreds" << 51,051) but it may be useful for people to keep in the back of their mind when designing other applications

Comment: also, with close, you need to use `printf >>` instead of `printf >`

Comment: @jhnc right, gawk can handle all those open files while other awks can't BUT gawk will slow down significantly as the number of "open" files gets larger as it has to reallocate arrays in exponentially larger chunks of memory as it goes along to do so. So, it's best to just close() them when you can if you can do so without THAT making your script slow down significantly.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk you can use `FPAT` to define the input fields with a regular expressions (in your case as a group of C=50 space-separated words), and print only the X-th group:

```
awk -v C=50 -v X=3 'BEGIN {FPAT="(\\S+\\s+){0," C-1 "}\\S+"}
  X<=NF {print $X}' huge_file.txt
```

This prints the third (X=3) group of 50 (C=50) columns, that is, columns 101 to 150. Of course if you have less than 150 columns, less than 50 are printed (or even nothing if there are less than 101).

You can also print at once all groups in different files:

```
awk -v C=50 'BEGIN {FPAT="(\\S+\\s+){0," C-1 "}\\S+"}
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > "small_file." i ".txt"}' huge_file.txt
```

If you have N=225 columns this creates 5 files named `small.1.txt`, ..., `small.5.txt`. File `small.1.txt` contains columns 1 to 50, `small.2.txt` contains columns 51 to 100, ..., `small.5.txt` contains columns 201 to 225.

Demo:

```
$ cat huge_file.txt 
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5

$ awk -v C=4 -v X=1 'BEGIN {FPAT="(\\S+\\s+){0," C-1 "}\\S+"}
  X<=NF {print $X}' huge_file.txt
A1 A2 A3 A4
B1 B2 B3 B4
C1 C2 C3 C4

$ awk -v C=4 -v X=2 'BEGIN {FPAT="(\\S+\\s+){0," C-1 "}\\S+"}
  X<=NF {print $X}' huge_file.txt
A5
B5
C5

$ awk -v C=4 'BEGIN {FPAT="(\\S+\\s+){0," C-1 "}\\S+"}
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > "small_file." i ".txt"}' huge_file.txt

$ ls small_file.*.txt
small_file.1.txt  small_file.2.txt

$ cat small_file.1.txt 
A1 A2 A3 A4
B1 B2 B3 B4
C1 C2 C3 C4

$ cat small_file.2.txt 
A5
B5
C5
```

Comment: Nice approach and for anyone reading this without GNU awk, you could do the same with any POSX awk with a loop `{ while ( match($0,"([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){0,"C-1"}[^[:space:]]+") ) { print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }` but you'd also need parens around the output file name, i.e. `("small_file." i ".txt")` and you may need to handle a "too many open files" issue if you end up with more concurrently open output files than your system can support for one process.

Answer (score 1):

`coreutils` might be better suited for this task (in bash):

```bash
ncols=$(( $(head -n1 $infile | tr -dc ' ' | wc -c) + 1 ))
stepsz=50

# Compose column ranges
paste -d- <(seq 1 $stepsz $ncols) <(seq $stepsz $stepsz $ncols) |
while read rng; do
  cut -d' ' -f$rng $infile > outfile_$rng
done
```

Comment: I had the same idea for `head | tr |  wc -c` but interestingly just `head | wc -w` seems faster (but it breaks on non-space whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

> it never works right, even if I use `FS = " "`.

This is default value of `FS` in GNU `AWK`, consider that

```
awk 'END{print FS==" "}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
1
```

setting built-in variable value to default will not change result.

> `{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}`

As there is field separator (`FS`) for input, there is often field separator (`OFS`) for output, used when you separate `print` arguments using commas, that is in this case it might be rewritten as

```
{print $1,$2,$3}
```

it is not only more concise, but you might change all separators by setting `OFS` value. Default value of `OFS` is single space. If you want to know more about `FS` or `OFS` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on an awk script that I think does what you need. Like Barmar's answer, it iterates over your fields with a for loop, but this one is simple enough to be understood by an awk novice. :) It this one redirects output to different files, and it does not require GNU awk.

```
BEGIN {
  cols=50
}

{
  n=1
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    output_file="file_" n
    printf("%s%s", $i, OFS) > output_file
    if (i%cols==0) n++
  }
  printf("%s", ORS) > output_file
}
```

You don't really need the `output_file` variable, but I feel that it makes things easier to read.

---

And because there was a comment about it, you should note that this does not explicitly close files. A version that closes files might have the following as the last line of the `for` loop:

```
    if (i%50==0) { n++; close(output_file) }
```

This closes files after we're done with them, but at the expense of overhead and a small speed hit. If you don't need it, I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: if you close, I think you also need `print >>` instead of `print >`.  Bigger problem: you aren't printing ORS to every output, just the final one for each line

Answer (score 0):

This question MAY result in awk having to create more output files than can be open simultaneously so here is an answer to avoid that problem without having to open and close the output file each time you write to it as that would be slow.

On a per-system basis there is a limit to how many files a process can have open at one time, on some systems `ulimit -n` will tell you that number. GNU awk can, if your OS supports it, allow you to appear to have more files than that open at once by internally managing opening/closing files on demand but will slow down a lot once it enters that phase. Other awks will just fail with a "too many open files" error ([google awk too many open files](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+%22too+many+open%22)). Below are 2 approaches to avoid that problem.

**1)** Open the input file once per output file and write to each output file one at a time:

If your input file might be too large to fit in memory then you could do this:

```
awk -v FS='^$' -v numCols=50 '
    FNR == 1 {
        if ( NR == 1 ) {
            nf = split($0,tmp," ")
            numFiles = int((nf - 1) / numCols) + 1
            while ( ARGC <= (numFiles + 1) ) {
                ARGV[ARGC++] = FILENAME
            }
        }
        close(out)
        out = "out." (++fileNr)
    }
    { line = substr($0,prevLgth[FNR] + 1) }
    match(line,"([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){0,"numCols-1"}[^[:space:]]+") {
        print substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH) > out
        prevLgth[FNR] += RSTART + RLENGTH
    }
' file
```

That just opens and closes both the input and the output file once per output file required and uses very little memory.

**2)** First read the input file into memory and then write one whole output file at a time:

Alternatively, if your input does fit in memory, this would also work in any POSIX awk:

```
awk -v FS='^$' -v numCols=50 '
    { lines[NR] = $0 }
    END {
        nf = split(lines[1],tmp," ")
        numFiles = int((nf - 1) / numCols) + 1
        for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++ ) {
            out = "out." fileNr
            for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=NR; lineNr++ ) {
                line = lines[lineNr]
                if ( match(line,"([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){0,"numCols-1"}[^[:space:]]+") ) {
                    print substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH) > out
                    lines[lineNr] = substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
                }
            }
            close(out)
        }
    }
' file
```

and would be a bit more efficient as it doesn't have to re-open the input file and re-read it's contents for every output file.

I'm using `-v FS='^$'` and `nf=split($0,tmp," ")` above instead of leaving `FS` set to `" "` and using `NF` for efficiency. I'm using `nf` from `nf=split($0,tmp," ")` instead of `NF` (and only doing it for the very first input line read) because some awks, e.g. GNU awk, will only do field splitting if a specific field such as `$1` **or `NF`** are mentioned in the script, otherwise they know you aren't using fields and so they don't need to waste time splitting the input into fields. Just in case you're using an awk that does field splitting anyway I'm setting `FS` to `^$` so it'll just make 1 attempt to match an empty line rather splitting on spaces multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `for` loops to iterate over the fields. The outer loop goes in groups of 50 and prints a newline after each group. The inner loop processes each group, printing each field followed by a blank.

```
awk '{for (start = 1; start <= NF; start += 50) {
        limit = start + 50 > NF ? NF : start + 50;
        for (cur = start; cur <= limit; cur++) {
            printf("%s ", $cur);
        }
        print;
    }' huge_file.txt > small_file.txt
```

Comment: that doesn't seem quite right